# Default Back Button task not happening

Tags: cordova, chocolatechip-ui

I have a simple code where i use Phonegap/Apache Cordova with chocolate chip UI. 
i call father from grandfather and son from father
so its like  Grandfather -> father -> son
Everything working fine. But there is a problem in back button. i cannot come back from father to grandfather or (from son to father). any idea ?

***the code***

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
      <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
      <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
      <title>ChocolateChip-UI Android</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="chui/chui-ios-3.5.2.min.css">
      <script src="chui/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
      <script src="chui/chui-3.5.2.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>

      <script>
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        function onDeviceReady(){}
        $(function() {

        });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <nav class="current">
        <h1>Family Tree</h1>
      </nav>
      <article id="main" class="current">
        <section>
          <ul class='list' role='list'>
            <li class='comp' data-goto="grandfather">
              <div>
                <h3>Grandfather</h3>
              </div>
              <aside>
                <span class='nav'></span>
              </aside>
            </li>
              </ul>
        </section>
      </article>

      <nav class='next'>
        <a href='#' class='button back'>Navigation</a>
        <h1>Family Tree</h1>
      </nav>
      <article id="grandfather" class='next'>
        <section>
          <ul class='list' role='list'>
            <li class='comp' data-goto="Father1">
              <div>
                <h3>Father1</h3>
              </div>
              <aside>
                <span class='nav'></span>
              </aside>
            </li>
             <li class='comp' data-goto="Father2">
              <div>
                <h3>Father2</h3>
              </div>
              <aside>
                <span class='nav'></span>
              </aside>
            </li>
             <li class='comp' data-goto="Father3">
              <div>
                <h3>Father3</h3>
              </div>
              <aside>
                <span class='nav'></span>
              </aside>
            </li>
              </ul>
        </section>
      </article>

       <nav class='next'>
        <a href='#' class='button back'>Navigation</a>
        <h1>Family Tree</h1>
      </nav>
      <article id="Father1" class='next'>
        <section>
          <ul class='list' role='list'>
            <li class='comp' data-goto="main">
              <div>
                <h3>Son1</h3>
              </div>
              <aside>
                <span class='nav'></span>
              </aside>
            </li>
             <li class='comp' data-goto="main">
              <div>
                <h3>Son2</h3>
              </div>
              <aside>
                <span class='nav'></span>
              </aside>
            </li>
             <li class='comp' data-goto="main">
              <div>
                <h3>Son3</h3>
              </div>
              <aside>
                <span class='nav'></span>
              </aside>
            </li>
              </ul>
        </section>
      </article>

      <nav class='next'>
        <a href='#' class='button back'>Navigation</a>
        <h1>Family Tree</h1>
      </nav>
      <article id="Father2" class='next'>
        <section>
          <ul class='list' role='list'>
            <li class='comp' data-goto="main">
              <div>
                <h3>Son4</h3>
              </div>
              <aside>
                <span class='nav'></span>
              </aside>
            </li>
             <li class='comp' data-goto="main">
              <div>
                <h3>Son5</h3>
              </div>
              <aside>
                <span class='nav'></span>
              </aside>
            </li>
              </ul>
        </section>
      </article>

      <nav class='next'>
        <a href='#' class='button back'>Navigation</a>
        <h1>Family Tree</h1>
      </nav>
      <article id="Father3" class='next'>
        <section>
          <ul class='list' role='list'>
            <li class='comp' data-goto="main">
              <div>
                <h3>Son6</h3>
              </div>
              <aside>
                <span class='nav'></span>
              </aside>
            </li>
              </ul>
        </section>
      </article>

      </body>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your back button doesn't need an href, and it will interfere with the built-in navigation. Chui.js takes care of the navigation behind the scenes. Take a look at the event handler for the back button press.

`///////////////////////////
    // Initialize Back Buttons:
    ///////////////////////////
    $('body').on('singletap', 'a.back', function() {
      if (this.classList.contains('back')) {
        $.UIGoBack();
      }
    });`

From the [documentation](http://www.chocolatechip-ui.com/documentation#back_button) for how to include a back button in your navigation bar

`<nav class='current'>
  <a class='button back'>Back</a>
  <h1>Candies</h1>
</nav>`